# one page and two <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

Tags: jquery

sorry for bad english. 
i have the page (index.html) with a line

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>.
```

this page loads ajax page (page2.html). this ajax page include 
 `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>` itself.
when page2.html load in main page (index.html) there is no problem with page2.html performance but another function with jquery in index.html got error like this "object dosent support this property" although it worked before page2.html load.
it seems that there are conflict between two jquery. if i remove `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>` from page2.html it work fine because index.html include this line but page2.html will not work independently. i tried $.noConflict(); and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this first**

It looks like you are trying to use two javascript frameworks on the same page. To do this you probably need to run `jQuery.noConflict()` after you load jquery, then instead of using **$()** to access jQuery functions, **use jQuery()**.

Refer this [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: i check this link but it doesnt work for me. index.html include $('#dialog').dialog({
autoOpen: false
});    and page2.html include $.getJSON(). where do put this jQuery.noConflict()?. both of $ will replace with jQuery?

Comment: Why dont you remove jquery-1.4.2.min.js from your AJAX page

Comment: it needs work alone(independent) too.it includes $.getjson() and need to jquery definition

Comment: it solved with adding $.noConflict() to ajax page no main page and i dont know why?

Answer (score 0):

You can load a fragment of a page so instead of doing

```
.load('page2.html');
```

do

```
.load('page2.html #contentDiv');
```

So that will just load a portion of the page that excludes the script tags.

Comment: @imez You may want to include all scripts in the main page that the child page might want to load

Comment: i need another page (ajax page) work independently (alone). if i remove scripts from that page it doesnt work

Comment: @imez I'm not saying remove the scripts from the child page. Just add all the scripts that it needs to the main page. Then you can just load the appropriate content.

Comment: this is a paradox with ajax concept.adding this scripts means adding large part of child page.

Comment: @imez, that's the problem, you're trying to load content from a page that also needs to be accessed independently. What would work better is if you had 2 pages defined page1.html and page2.html that loaded content that could not be accessed independently _content.html.

Comment: it solved with adding $.noConflict() before child page script and no mainpage.